# Which of the following map are constant ?? IIT-kanpur PhD paper

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Which of the following maps are constant?

(a) $f : D → C$ such that $f$ is analytic and $f(D) ⊂ R.$

(b) $f : D → D$ such that $f$ is analytic and $f([−1/2, 1/2])$ = {0}.

(c) $f : C → C$ such that $f$ is analytic and $Re(f)$ is bounded.

(d) $f : C → C$ such that $f$ is analytic and $f$ is bounded on the real and imaginary axes

*My works *:

option  a),b) and c)  will true  by *Liouville's theorem* that  is  real value  and analytics  implies constant

option d) will be  false  take $f(z) =e^{iz^2}$

Please  verify  whether I am right /wrong ?  Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I'm right, my answer is correct